# How to query bigQuery view definition?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to query/search all of my bigQuery views definition?
Not via API but on the BigQuery query UI?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so.  BigQuery doesn't expose metadata through views, which is how most other databases handle this.

Comment: Submit the form linked in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063#comment9 to get (alpha) access to INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to do this from the BigQuery UI using the following SELECT statement:

```
select table_name,view_definition
from myDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

The key to getting it to work was the case sensitivity of 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS'.